# XSLT/XSLFO: Get Total Number of Pages out of Multiple Fo:Page-Sequence in a Single PDF

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I have several `<fo:page-sequence/>`, each of them initialize the page number from 1. I am able to get access to the total page number of each fo:page-sequence by using `<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="page-id"/>`. But how can I sum them up to get the total page number of the entire pdf?

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:template match="a/b/c//d" priority="50">
    <xsl:param name="node" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($node/ancestor::c) &lt;= 0 or count($node/ancestor::c[parent::c]/preceding-sibling::c) &lt;= 0">
        <fo:page-sequence id="pages-{count($node/parent::c/preceding-sibling::c)}-{count($node/preceding-sibling::d)}" master-reference="pages" format="i">
            <xsl:call-template name="header_footer"/>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:next-match/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <fo:page-sequence id="pages-{count($node/parent::c/preceding-sibling::c)}-{count($node/preceding-sibling::d)}" master-reference="pages" initial-page-number="{if ($node/preceding-sibling::d) then 'auto' else '1'}" format="1">
            <xsl:call-template name="header_footer"/>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:next-match/>
            </fo:flow>
          </fo:page-sequence>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The xml strucutre is:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
     <c>
      <d/>
      <d/>
      ...
     </c>
     <c>
      <d/>
      <d/>
      ...
     </c>
     ...
  </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

Now I can get each page-sequence's total page numbers by using

```
<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="pages-0-end"/>
<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="pages-1-end"/>
<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="pages-2-end"/>
...
```

But how can I sum the value of all total page numbers for each page-sequence and get a total page number for the entire pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `axf:physical-page-number` extension (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.physical-page-number) to get the physical page number of the last page.

You might, though I've never tried it, be able to use `axf:physical-page-number` in combination with `axf:orgin-id` to get the number of pages between two FOs.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't have to get page numbers across different FOs so I only use <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="id" axf:physical-page-number="true"/>